# Finding a position in an array of a maxmum point from a fits file, pyfits

Tags: python, arrays, pyfits

I have a Fits file with 12 different arrays of information about the image. I can find the maximum value of the array I want to look at, MAG_AUTO, by using the line.

```
a=pyfits.getdata(data1).MAG_AUTO
```

Where data1 is my data set from the fits file. But I am after the position in the array where the maximum value occurs. How would I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer, the following command produces the maximum for a set a given files,

```
 for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        a=pyfits.getdata(arg).MAG_AUTO
        arr=numpy.array(a)
        indices = heapq.nlargest(10,xrange(len(arr)),key=arr.__getitem__)
        print indices
```

Comment: thanks for updating.  i was curious about this after seeing the question but couldn't work out how to do it from the docs.

Comment: No worries, looking back on the question i probably should have worded it better. And it didnt really matter that I was using pyfits because that was about the only line of code i actually had working! I think the pyfits might have made some people ignore my question.